# "timed out while connecting to named pipe visual studio" When trying to open a windows form in .CORE 5.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hey guys i will try to explain as good as i cant.
I moved 3 windows forms and a database class by dragging and dropping them to a class library. This has caused me 400 errors. Only the database class is openable. The forms (all 3) give me this error.
All errors are found in the designer of each form.
I use .CORE 5.0

What i have noticed:
The smallest form out of the 3 forms, has the least errors.

Can someone help ? thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Errors are bound to occur when you modify the position of a form, and you should try to look at those errors and fix them.